# Embedding a dynamic form in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

**General info**

I am working with Symfony 2.8. In this question two entities are the subject. ObjectElementTask and Activity. I have embedded Activity as a collection inside ObjectElementTask. So far, everything is fine and up and running.

**Problem**

I added a evenlistener in ActivityType. Because a part of the ActivityForm inside the ObjectElementTaskForm has to be dynamic (based on the authenticated user that is using the form...)

When I view the ActivityForm direct: through the ActivityController (which calls the form with this code: `$editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ActivityType', $activity);`) the eventlistener is working.

When I view the ObjectElementTaksForm I get a exception:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\ActivityType::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface, none given, called in /home/vpcont1q/public_html/test/src/AppBundle/Form/ObjectElementTaskType.php on line 62

**My Guess**

I guess because inside the ObjectElementTaksForm, the ActivityForm gets called on a other way then inside the ActivityController. And then the argument (registered in the services.yml) doesn't get passed. How to make sure the registered service gets called when embedding the form? Or... am I looking in the wrong direction.

**Code**

Below my Types and the services.yml part:

This is my ActivityType:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{

    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('executionDate')
            ->add('status'),
            ->add('scheduledDate')
           
        // grab the user, do a quick sanity check that one exists
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'You are NOT an authenticated user!'
            );
        }
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($user) {
            //TODO
        });
        


    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Activity'
        ));
    }
}
```

And this is my ObjectElementTaskType:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class ObjectElementTaskType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('activities', 'collection', array(
            'entry_type' => new ActivityType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ObjectElementTask',
        ));
    }
}
```

I have registered the ActivityForm as a service with the token as a argument:

```
  app.form.activity:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ActivityType
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

**EDIT**

This seems to work:

Instead of registering the ActivityType as a service I registered the ObjectElementTask as a service (also with the Tokenstorage).
I don't use the ActivityType other then embedded in the ObjectElementTaskType so that's why I removed the ActivityType as a service in services.yml.

```
  app.form.object_element_task:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ObjectElementTaskType
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

And in the ObjectElementTaskType I added the construct:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class ObjectElementTaskType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {        
$tokenStorage = $this->tokenStorage;
```

And in the buildform I added the tokenstorage as a parameter in the ActivityType class declaration:

```
    ->add('activities', 'collection', array(
    'entry_type' => new ActivityType($tokenStorage),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    ))
```

The ActivityType I haven't changed. Is this a workaround or the way to do it?